# QMake: how to properly create a shared object with symbolic links at make install

Tags: shared-libraries, symlink, qmake

I have built a library that uses qmake as the build mechanism. I am using `TEMPLATE=lib` and `CONFIG=dll`. My problem is that the symbolic links to the library are being created when I run make and are for the current directory not `/usr/lib/` like when I run make install. make install then tried to move these links over and ends up just putting 4 copies of the library in `/usr/lib`. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: Obviously some flavor of *nix.